# Does marketing cloud have a Database or Can we access it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data

Can somebody tell me that marketing cloud have any database or if yes which database MC use to store data extension or list data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFMC is running on MS SQL, where each Data Extension is created as a unique table. It is however not possible to connect directly to the DB, as the data is only exposed through the UI and API. There are multiple examples here on SFSE, on how to connect external applications either through SOAP/REST API for real time, or through Enhanced FTP/Data Extracts for high volume bulk data loads. Please provide more context, for more tailored examples and use cases.

In your case, where data is stored on AWS S3, I assume you store flat files on it (e.g CSV). You can use [AWS S3 SFTP](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/) and connect it to SFMC as a new [File Location](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5) - then you can use S3 for fetching data with [Import File](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_an_import_activity.htm) and exporting with [Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_data_extract_file.htm&type=5) and [File Transfer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your electric response. We want to Read/Write the data from AWS S3 to Marketing cloud so how should we proceed, could you suggest.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that